# Why does the Rails sanitizer remove hrefs that contain capitalized URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitization

An example:

```
[Dev]>   ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize('<a href="http://google.com">test</a>')
=> '<a href="http://google.com">test</a>'
[Dev]>   ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize('<a href="Http://google.com">test</a>')
=> '<a>test</a>'
```

Extremely frustrating!

Comment: I can confirm I'm getting the same result here 3.0.1. I'm afraid I can't even find documentation of this function in the rails API though :(. Maybe my searching skills are rusty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the method `contains_bad_protocols?` in action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb. This method is defined as:

```
def contains_bad_protocols?(attr_name, value)
    uri_attributes.include?(attr_name) && 
    (value =~ /(^[^\/:]*):|(&#0*58)|(&#x70)|(%|&#37;)3A/ 
        && !allowed_protocols.include?(value.split(protocol_separator).first))
end
```

And allowed_protocols as:

```
self.allowed_protocols = Set.new(%w(ed2k ftp http https irc mailto news gopher nntp 
    telnet webcal xmpp callto feed svn urn aim rsync tag ssh sftp rtsp afs))
```

Thus:

```
allowed_protocols.include? 'http' => true
allowed_protocols.include? 'Http' => false
```